# Restkit - how can i add an operation with priority?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

i'm using RESTKit and i saw that the operation queue uses NSOperationQueue that supports priority.

the problem is, that the RKObjectManager doesn't have a method to add an action with priority. and i prefer not to change the implementation in the pod file.

i'm looking at "getObjectsAtPath". inside, theres "RKObjectRequestOperation" which i can assign "SetQueuePriority" - but again, this is changing the 3rd party code.

Any way to do it inside my code?

thanks!

Comment: I can inherit from the object manager and support it. But im not sure if thats intended

Comment: I've implemented manually without using the already written restkit object manager sadly.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I exactly need what you were looking for

Comment: @Raj yes, i extended the RKObjectManager and copied logic from there, and added a support.
There's no built in support for priority sadly

Comment: Did you fork from GitHub Restkit so that I can take a look into it?

Comment: If I remember correctly we imported it from a pod, but you can take from github. If you are still in troubles tell me? I'll find the relevant code next week.

Answer (score 0):

I generally wouldn't recommend you to change the priorities. If you need to control the overall order of the downloads then you should control this outside of RestKit and probably triggering the next download from the completion block.

That said, if you do want to do this then you can use `appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:method:path:parameters:` and `enqueueObjectRequestOperation:` on the `RKObjectManager`.

Comment: i have background operations that should run in parallel with low priority. so i don't have other choice.
your solution makes me re-write already written code inside the RKObjectManager